How to run a YML file in GitLab CI/CD with JMX and CSV files?
I’m trying to set up a GitLab CI/CD pipeline that runs a JMeter performance test using a .jmx file and a .csv file. I have a JMX file (GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx) and a CSV file (Config_Setup_LotInfo_sample.csv) that I want to use in the pipeline.
So far, I have been able to create a basic .gitlab-ci.yml file, but I’m unsure how to correctly configure it to run the JMeter tests with these files. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax or steps to configure the GitLab CI/CD pipeline for this scenario?
Here's what I’ve tried so far in my .gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:

jmeter
report

variables:
Compression and general settings
FF_USE_FASTZIP: "true"
ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest"
CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest"
Project and environment settings
ENV: "prd"
PROJECT: "nvis"
TARGET: "jmeter"
JMeter test files
JMX_FILE: "GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx"
CSV_FILE_PATH: "results.csv"
JMX_WRITE: "result_output"
jmeter-build:
stage: jmeter
image: registry.example.com/jmeter_base:1.0.3
before_script:
# Copy JMX file to JMeter directory
- cp JMeter-sample/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3
- mkdir -p "$BUILD_PATH"
script:
# Execute JMeter test
- sh jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" -n -t /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx -l /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.csv -e -o /GIS_2CSV_sample_sya
- cp /opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.csv /builds/example/devops/jmeter/report && cp -r /GIS_2CSV_sample_sya /builds/example/devops/jmeter/report
report_job:
stage: report
image: alpine:3.8
dependencies:
- jmeter-build
I'm facing issues with properly linking the JMX and CSV files, and I want to ensure the pipeline successfully runs the test and generates the report. Here’s what I’ve tried, but I’m not sure if the file paths and syntax are correct.
Could anyone help me identify any issues in the .gitlab-ci.yml file, especially with how to run the JMeter test using the .jmx file with the .csv file in the GitLab CI/CD pipeline?
Thanks in advance!

Example Gitlab CI config file to run GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx file in the root of your Gitlab repository and use Config_Setup_LotInfo_sample.csv will look like:
stages:
  - jmeter-test

load-test:
  stage: jmeter-test
  variables:
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive
  image:
    name: debian:latest
  script:
    - apt update
    - apt install -y openjdk-17-jdk-headless wget
    - wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.6.3.tgz
    - tar xzf apache-jmeter-5.6.3.tgz
    - apache-jmeter-5.6.3/bin/./jmeter.sh -n -t GIS_2CSV_sample_sya.jmx -l results.csv
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - results.csv
    expire_in: 1 month

It downloads and installs JMeter and runs the test saving the KPIs into results.csv file and archiving the artifact so you could analyze results.
